# Symfony 5: Firewalls and Access Control for access

Tags: firewall, access-control, symfony5

I am designing an API with the following endpoint:

```
/album/{identifier}
```

To access this endpoint users should either be fully authenticated and accessed as the owner of the album OR have a valid invite code which is passed in the query string.

I can't seem to get this working with the Firewall, access control and a voter.  It seems I can only have total anonymous access but with an invite code or the user as a fully authenticated member.

My firewall is as follows:

```
    firewalls:
        login:
          pattern: ^/login
          methods: [POST]
          stateless: true
          anonymous: true
          provider: user_provider
          json_login:
        ...
        album:
          methods: [GET]
          pattern: ^/album/%identifier_regex%
          stateless: true
          anonymous: lazy 
        api:
          pattern: ^/
          stateless: true
          provider: jwt
          guard:
              authenticators:
                  - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

I need to include the album endpoint here so that it is not blocked by the jwt authenticator which the majority of other endpoints will require.

I'm also slightly confused by the need for both firewall rules here and an access control list.  It seems to me that I should be able to configure all of this alone with the firewall rules and I'm just duplicating it with the access control rules

I then have the access control list of:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [POST] }
    - { path: ^/album/%identifier_regex%, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Finally, I have a voter in my controller that will check that the user is either the owner of the album or if they have a valid invite code for the album they can access.

However, with the configuration above, even if they're logged in and authenticated (they have a JWT) the token->getUser() always returns an anonymous user.  If I change the config and remove the 'album' matcher under the firewall, it will work perfectly for authenticated users, but then anonymous users are of course blocked by the JWT guard.

Surely it is possible to have a resource that is both accessible by authenticated and non-authenticated users alike?